# Using Gulp Zip to zip all the files in a folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, gulp, gulp-zip

I am using [gulp-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-zip) to zip up my source files. So I have a main folder called FIFA which has other sub folders which might have more sub folders and files. In additon the FIFA folder also has files like my package.json, gulp.js and some other files. I want to basically use gulp-zip to zip up my entire project and create a folder called distribution and save the zip inside it. So this is the code i used.

```
gulp.task('zip', function () {
    return gulp.src('./*,')
        .pipe(zip('test.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./distribution'));
});
```

The issue is that although a zip is created inside the distribution folder that zip only contains the files inside the FIFA folder, all the files inside the subfolders of FIFA are not there. So for instance if FIFA has a subfolder called ronaldo and ronaldo contains goal.js that goal.js is not in the zip. What have i done wrong? Please advice.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try it with two `*`

```
gulp.task('zip', function () {
    return gulp.src('./**')
        .pipe(zip('test.zip'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./distribution'));
});
```

---

> What's the difference between `*` and `**`?

One star means all files, no folders - too stars will be more deep and also include all the folders inside the specified folder.

> And for instance if you wanted to do two stars to include all folders EXCEPT one specific folder , is that possible to do also?

You can use an exclamation mark like `!./excludedDir`, pass `src` as an array with the `!...` as one of the values

Comment: This will zip everything in that given folder, so it might take some time. You might need to be more specific with your folder if that zips too much. @Dinero

Comment: worked like a charm i can accept your answer in 7 minutes can you explain why ** makes the difference and also is there a reference for this?

Comment: One star means all files, no folders - too stars will be more deep and also include all the folders inside the specified folder. @Dinero

Comment: And for instance if you wanted to do two stars to include all folders EXCEPT one specific folder , is that possible to do also ? Thanks so much for explaining.

Comment: You can use an exclamation mark like !./excludedDir, pass src as an array with the !... as one of the values @Dinero

Comment: When I use '/**' to recursively add files into zip file, I got error below:  EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory .But '/*' works corrctly. Any ideas where I did wrong? @baao?

Comment: @ericchan1336 hard to say without knowing something about structure and code. Consider to ask a new question, maybe with a link to this one to avoid getting it closed as a duplicate.